# Array of tables

Tags: r

I want to write some R tables into an excel file. So I have the follow?

```
 data <- list.files(path=getwd())
 n <- length(list)
 for (i in 1:n) 
     {
      data1 <- read.csv(data[i])
      outline <- data1[,2]
      outline <- as.table(outline)
      print(outline)   # this prints all n tables
      write.csv(outline, 'Test.csv') # this only writes the last table
     }
```

But I only get the last file written into the csv file. Not all of them. How would I fix this?

Comment: In communicating about R it's better not to use the term "array" unless you are talking about the data structure called 'array'. You are also causing some potential problems by converting to a 'table' which is really a `matrix`, since `write.csv`expects to get a data.frame. And if you were expecting to actually tabulate, you shouldn't use `as.table` since it will NOT tabulate the values.

Comment: @DWin: I was considering storing each matrix into an array and then writing the array into an excel file.

Comment: I'm not sure further sensible comment is possible until you describe the full problem. If you are tabulating values you surely do NOT want to use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your writing to `test.csv` every time. So you keep over writing files. You need to change the filename for each step to keep the different files.

try:

```
data <- list.files(path=getwd())
 n <- length(list)
 for (i in 1:n) 
     {
      data1 <- read.csv(data[i])
      outline <- data1[,2]
      outline <- as.table(outline)
      print(outline)   # this prints all n tables
      name <- paste0(i,"X.csv")
      write.csv(outline, name)
     }
```

Looking at your code perhaps you want this instead:

```
data <- list.files(path=getwd())
     n <- length(list)
     for (i in 1:n) 
         {
          data1 <- read.csv(data[i])
          outline <- data1[,2]
          outline <- as.data.frame(table(outline))
          print(outline)   # this prints all n tables
          name <- paste0(i,"X.csv")
          write.csv(outline, name)
     }
```

Comment: The thing is I want all of the tables on the SAME excel file. Not separate Excel files for each one. So instead of overwriting the file, I want each table to appear below the table before it on the same Excel file.