# How to not overwrite file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to copy and paste tables from R into Excel. Consider the following code from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942917/array-of-tables):

```
    data <- list.files(path=getwd())
    n <- length(list)
    for (i in 1:n) 
     {
      data1 <- read.csv(data[i])
      outline <- data1[,2]
      outline <- as.data.frame(table(outline))
      print(outline)   # this prints all n tables
      name <- paste0(i,"X.csv")
      write.csv(outline, name)
      }
```

This code writes each table into separate Excel files (i.e. "1X.csv", "2X.csv", etc..). Is there any way of "shifting" each table down some rows instead of rewriting the previous table each time? I have also tried this code:

```
 output <- as.data.frame(output)
 wb = loadWorkbook("X.xlsx", create=TRUE)
 createSheet(wb, name = "output")
 writeWorksheet(wb,output,sheet="output",startRow=1,startCol=1)
 writeNamedRegion(wb,output,name="output")
 saveWorkbook(wb)
```

But this does not copy the dataframes exactly into Excel.

Comment: Does it work if you create a full table in R and then write the table to a single file?

Comment: write to a connection, and open the file with "a" instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think, as mentioned in the comments, the way to go is to first merge the data frames in R and then writing them into (one) output file:

```
# get vector of filenames
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd())

# for each filename: load file and create outline
outlines <- lapply(filenames, function(filename) {
  data <- read.csv(filename)
  outline <- data[,2]
  outline <- as.data.frame(table(outline))
  outline
})

# merge all outlines into one data frame (by appending them row-wise)
outlines.merged <- do.call(rbind, outlines)

# save merged data frame
write.csv(outlines.merged, "all.csv")
```

Answer (score 4):

Despite what microsoft would like you to believe, .csv files are not excel files, they are a common file type that can be read by excel and many other programs.

The best approach depends on what you really want to do.  Do you want all the tables to read into a single worksheet in excel?  If so you could just write to a single file using the `append` argument to the `write.csv` or other functions. Or use a connection that you keep open so each new one is appended.  You may want to use `cat` to put a couple of newlines before each new table.

Your second attempt looks like it uses the XLConnect package (but you don't say, so it could be something else).  I would think this the best approach, how is the result different from what you are expecting?

Comment: @Greg Snow: Yes the second attempt is the XLConnect package . It doesn't copy the tables exactly. IS transpose the names, and puts frequency as a column header.

Comment: +1 for the `append` argument tip, especially.  When I do this, that's what I do.

Comment: @proton, I expect that it is `as.data.frame` rather than anything from the XLConnect package that is causing the problem (what does the data frame look like?).  Try using `as.data.frame.matrix` instead.